# How to receive document deletion event from MongoDb Kafka connector?

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have created a Kafka connector  for reading change events for my Mongo database collection. I have set it to return full document in case of any change. It's working fine for new document creations and their updations. I am receiving those events. But in case of document deletion, I am not getting any event.

How can I get document deletion event from that connector?

(I am not sure what else to add here. Let me know if more details are needed)

Answer (score 0):

Debezium can return deletion operations. I'm not sure if the official MongoDB Source connector can